# Discord-py When a user is typing, how to make the bot to follow the typing and when the user stop, the bot also stop typing in a specific channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When a user is typing, how to make the bot to also start the typing event in a certain channel and stop when the user who was typing stopped.

ctx.trigger_typing/ctx.typing cannot be used since we need to track the user if he/she is typing.

So how to do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

enabling `intents.typing` and turning on the intents within the Discord developer portal can access the `on_typing` event, you can just enable all intents from your code like:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

The typing event can be called simply using an `on_typing` event,

```
@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    print(f"{user} is typing message in {channel} {when}")
```

If you want to get your bot to have a typing status, you can use `ctx.typing():` followed with what It would send.

Here's an `on_message` event example,

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async with message.channel.typing():
        await message.channel.send('Typing status invoked')
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Command usage, you can also add a sleep event to control the typing time

```py
@client.command()
async def type(ctx):
    async with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await ctx.send("Typing...")
```

Comment: what about the [`on_typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_typing) event?

Comment: sorry I need to update, I found some information about the typing event, thankyou @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: Sorry about that, I just never knew that existed within Discord's API, hope that helps

Comment: but how to track the user to see if he/she is typing? like when the user is typing, the bot should also have a typing status in a certain channel, and when the user stopped, the bot should also stop, how to do that