# Discord.py - How to detect that a user finish typing?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that can mimic a normal user. One of the thing that the bot will have to do is to display "The bot is typing ...", synchronously with the player it mimics (delay of 1 or 2 seconds is not a problem).
This implies two things:

1. The bot needs to detect when the copied user has begun to type.
2. The bot needs to detect when the user has finished.

In the first case, the `on_typing()` event is great.

The second case is more complicated. The user can have finished to type its message because he send it or because he deleted it.

Detecting he send his message is easy with `on_message`. But with a deleted message ? I didn't find anything. There is no such event in the `Client` documentation. Does anyone knows a workaround ?

EDIT :
I know how to detect if a user started to type. The problem is how to detect he has finished.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord-py When a user is typing, how to make the bot to follow the typing and when the user stop, the bot also stop typing in a specific channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988360/discord-py-when-a-user-is-typing-how-to-make-the-bot-to-follow-the-typing-and-w)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Dominik !
Unfortunately, the given answer in that link does not cover my problem. It give different solutions on how to detect a user beginning to type, but not when he finished.

Comment: Good question, but there isn't really an answer to it. The discord API doesn't provide a websocket event dispatched when someone stops typing

Comment: Is there a way to deduce this information in the discord API ? 
Or, as a workaround, checking if a specific user is still typing ?

Comment: You probably just want to show your "The bot is typing..." message for a second or two after you get the typing message. Then let it expire if there's not been another typing event. If you want to be very precisely tracking the user's activity, you could perhaps be more precise (so you could clear the message immediately after a message was sent, for example), but just letting the typing message time out is probably the easiest way to go.