# I am trying to make a discord bot in which I want that as soon as user type into command channel his/her discord id must be printed

Tags: python, discord

```
 if message.content.startswith('$register'):
        await message.channel.send('You are registered successfully')
        userk = print(client.user.id)
```

I am using Discord.py and Iam trying to get the Discord user id of a user when they type into a channel. But I am not able to find the specific command for that current  api of discord is not saying anything about that.the above code is only printing my bot's id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65988801/6251742 ?

Comment: no friend I want the user id should be printed

Comment: What is `client` ?

Comment: it is client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Get the author of the message

You need to look the id of the author.

API:

- [discord.on_message(message)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#messages): Get a message, a Message,
- [class discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message): look for author attribute, a Member,
- [class discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member): look id attribute.

```py
if message.content.startswith('$register'):
    await message.channel.send('You are registered successfully')
    print(message.author.id)
```

Comment: it will give me message id I already tried this

Comment: I want user id friend

Comment: message.*author*.id?

Comment: It gives the id of the message not the user

Comment: Can you copy the code that display the id of the message? Because the documentation say otherwise

Comment: ok just doing and sending you

Comment: sorry my mistake your code worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possible answer here:

[Discord-py When a user is typing, how to make the bot to follow the typing and when the user stop, the bot also stop typing in a specific channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65988801/6251742)

> EDIT:
>
> enabling `intents.typing` and turning on the intents within the
> Discord developer portal can access the `on_typing` event, you can
> just enable all intents from your code like:
>
> ````
> discord.Client(intents=intents) ```
>
> The typing event can be called simply using an ``on_typing`` event, 
> ``` @client.event async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
>     print(f"{user} is typing message in {channel} {when}")
> ````

Here is an example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    print(f"{user.id=}")
```

Check the [discord.on_typing(channel, user, when)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_typing) documentation.
`user` parameter can be a User or a Member, but either way, it have an `id` attribute.

Comment: it is only printing the id of the bot

Comment: From the documentation, > user (Union[User, Member]) – The user that started typing.

Comment: my query is not  related typing I just want want that when a user type $register his or her user id must be printed

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding of your issue thanks to your comments ! I've writter another answer, tell me if I'm right or wrong :)